# Why do my earbuds not play voices and muffle the music?

Tags: windows, audio, windows-8.1

I'm on an Asus q550lf-bsi7t21 with Windows 8.1 installed. I have Realtek HD Audio drivers installed. While listening to music/watching videos voices are muffled/nonexistent and some of the music part is also not playing.

This problem only started a couple days ago (I haven't installed anything/done any software or hardware changes beyond automatic windows updates).

My speakers work perfectly fine, and the headphones (I've tried 2 different pairs so far) work on other computers/devices, so I know it's an issue with my laptop. In the past, both these pairs worked with my laptop.

I've looked elsewhere for solutions and putting the earbuds in slightly but not all the way into the jack doesn't help at all.

Comment: I have experienced a similar muffled sound when the electrical connection was poor.  Rotating the audio plug in the jack fixed it.

Comment: I've tried that before it didn't do anything :/

Comment: I'm having the same issue too. By any chance do you have a 5.1 sound setup with speaker fill etc?

Comment: In my case, I have a TRRS port, and a TRS headphone.  It used to work perfectly. I also have realtek sound. and WIndows 7.  Just quit yesterday.